# Does Registering a Salvaged Car in California Require a "Brake and Light Certificate"?

Tags: registration

My car was totaled after the accident and I salvaged it from the insurance company.  I didn't realize I had to pay more fees to the California Department of Motor Vehicles and do some extra things.  Does anyone know if the DMV requires a "Brake and Light Certificate" in order to re-register a salvaged vehicle?

Comment: In the future, don't sign your car over the the insurance company to begin with. Just make them pay out a claim for the value of the vehicle minus whatever deduction they claim they'd sell it for.

Comment: @R.. Yeah.  Lesson learned for sure!  First accident in 20 years of driving, so I'm not too accustomed to dealing with the insurance company :)

Comment: To clarify, the arrangement you probably want in a situation like this is to sign an agreement with the insurance company that you agree the damages are just under the threshold that would constitute a total loss. Alternatively you can challenge their valuation of the vehicle and take them to court for the damages; if the vehicle value is low enough that you can use small claims court, you may essentially automatically win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the California DMV webpage [How to Reregister a Salvage Vehicle](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/pubs/brochures/howto/htvr13.htm), it says:

You will need…

- An Application for Title or Registration (REG 343) form (PDF)
- Proof of ownership
- A Verification of Vehicle (REG 31) form or CHP inspection certificate
- Brake and light adjustment certificates
- Appropriate fees

You may also need…

- An Application for Salvage Certificate or Nonrepairable Vehicle Certificate (REG 488C) form
- Smog certification
- Weight certificate
- Vehicle/Vessel Transfer and Reassignment Form (REG 262)
- Statement of Facts (REG 256) form (PDF)
- Declaration of Gross Vehicle Weight (GVW)/Combined Gross Vehicle Weight (CGW) (REG 4008) form
- Permanent Trailer Identification (PTI) Application and Certification (REG 4017) form
  To surrender existing license plates

So, to answer your question, it appears **you will need the Brake and light adjustment certificates**. Please note towards the bottom of the CA DMV site, there is an exception listed as to the need of the certificates, but that looks pretty remote.